# Least Squares Estimation for CRD experiments

Tags: multiple-regression, optimization, least-squares, experiment-design

**Setup**

Let us use the following model for a Completely Randomised Designed (CRD) experiment:

$$ Y_{ij}= \mu + \tau_i + \epsilon_{ij}$$
where the errors $\epsilon _{ij}$ ~ Normal ($0, \sigma ^2 $) and are independent (and uncorrelated). Here, $i$ refers to a particular treatment where $i = 1 . . .t$ and $j$ refers to the $j$th observation of the $i$th treatment and $j = 1 . . .n_i$.

If we want to find Least Squares Estimates for $\mu$ or $\tau _i$ (for a fixed $i$) , then we need to minimise the sum of the squares of the errors. In other words, we want to minimise:

$$ S =\sum _{i=1}^t \sum _{j=1}^{n_i} \epsilon _{ij}^2 = \sum _{i=1}^t \sum _{j=1}^{n_i} (Y_{ij}-\mu - \tau_i)^2 $$

We can then look to find a suitable value of $\mu$ or $\tau_i$ (for a fixed $i$) respectively by trying to the value of that variable that minimises the sum.

**Attempt**

In order to minimise this sum, we first differentiate with respect to the variable of choice. If this is $\mu$, we get:

$$ \frac{ \partial S}{\partial \mu} = -2 \sum _{i=1}^t \sum _{j=1}^{n_i} (Y_{ij} - \hat{\mu} - \hat{\tau}_i) = \color{red}{ -2 \sum _{i=1}^t \big{(}\sum _{j=1}^{n_i}(Y_{ij} - n_i \hat{\mu} - n_i \hat{\tau} _i) \big{)}} = 0$$

**Question**

My question is about what the justification is for the step in red.

I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious, but I can't see why we can multiply $\mu$ and $\tau _i$ by these constants and have the sums remain equal. This is part of the solution in my textbook (and a similar principle is used for minimising with respect to $\tau _i$) and I would be interested in an explanation of why we are able to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\frac{ \partial S}{\partial \mu} =0\implies  -2 \sum _{i=1}^t \sum _{j=1}^{n_i} \left(Y_{ij} - \hat{\mu} - \hat{\tau}_i\right)  = 0\tag 1\label 1
$$

Expanding the sum in $\eqref 1$ yields the following normal equation:

\begin{align}\sum _{i=1}^t \sum _{j=1}^{n_i} Y_{ij}-\sum _{i=1}^t \sum _{j=1}^{n_i} \hat \mu-\sum _{i=1}^t \sum _{j=1}^{n_i}\hat \tau_i&=0\\\implies Y_{\cdot\cdot}-N\hat \mu -n_1\hat \tau_1-n_2\hat \tau_2 -\cdots -n_t\hat \tau_t&=0.\tag 2\label 2\end{align}

---

To see what's happening, we will go one summation at a time:

\begin{align}\sum _{i=1}^t \sum _{j=1}^{n_i} \left(Y_{ij} - \hat{\mu} - \hat{\tau}_i\right) &=\sum _{i=1}^t\left(\sum _{j=1}^{n_i} Y_{ij} - n_i\hat{\mu}-n_i\hat{\tau}_i\right) \\&= \sum _{i=1}^t \sum _{j=1}^{n_i} Y_{ij}-\sum _{i=1}^tn_i\hat{\mu}-\sum _{i=1}^tn_i\hat{\tau}_i\end{align} which leads to $\eqref 2.$

So, when they wrote $\sum _{i=1}^t \left(\sum _{j=1}^{n_i}(Y_{ij} - n_i \hat{\mu} - n_i \hat{\tau} _i) \right) ,$ it was an error/typo for $\sum _{j=1}^{n_i}$ hasn't been applied and yet there are $ n_i \hat{\mu} - n_i \hat{\tau} _i. $

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by your last line. I assume $Y_{\cdot \cdot}$ is defined as $\sum _{i=1}^t \sum_{j=1}^{n_i} Y_{ij}$ and that $N = n_1 + n_2 + . . . n_t$? Is that correct?

Comment: Correct, it is.

Comment: Similarly, solve for $\hat \tau_i$ to get the other normal equations.

Comment: Your last line is in the form: $\big{(} \sum_{i=1}^t \sum_{j=1}^{n_i} Y_{ij} \big{)} - \sum_{i=1}^t (n_i \hat{ \mu}+ n_i \hat{\tau}_i) = 0$ but this isn't quite the same as the form of the line in red in the question - although maybe I'm missing something

Comment: This is what is happening: you first operate the second summation, then the first summation. I am not seeing any intricacies here. And you are also stating the right things and yet you are not able to comprehend. So, why do you think the summation won't operate this way?

Comment: What I'm seeing is that your answer is: $ \sum_{i=1}^t ( \big{(} \sum_{j=1}^{n_i} Y_{ij} \big{)} - n_i \hat{ \mu}- n_i \hat{\tau}_i ) = 0$ which is almost in the desired form, but we have brackets around the inside sum which is not necessarily the same as the expression in my question without some additional justification. We want $ \sum_{i=1}^t \big{(} \sum_{j=1}^{n_i} Y_{ij} - n_i \hat{ \mu}- n_i \hat{\tau}_i \big{)} = 0$ which is different unless there is a reason I'm not following that allows us to join the sums

Comment: Unfortunately @FD_bfa, even I am not able to understand where it is actually creating the problem: you first operate one summation, then the other. There is no intricacies of interchanging.

Comment: For example: $\sum_{n=1}^{10}(n+2) \neq \big{(} \sum_{n=1}^{10} n \big{)} +2$  so (at least in this example) the extra parenthesis **does** make a difference

Comment: Are you saying that $  \big{(} \sum_{j=1}^{n_i} Y_{ij} \big{)} - n_i \hat{ \mu}- n_i \hat{\tau}_i $ is the same as $ \sum_{j=1}^{n_i} (Y_{ij} - n_i \hat{ \mu}- n_i \hat{\tau}_i )$? And if so, why is that different to the example in my comment above?

Comment: Of course $\sum_{n=1}^{10} (n+2) =\left(\sum_{n=1}^{10 }n\right ) + \sum_{n=1}^{10 }2.$ But I have now noticed where it all went off the rails.

Comment: I would edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've marked the answer as accepted now.

Comment: Well, I am sorry for actually not noticing rhe main thing and yet we were going all in on what was right and wrong. Misinterpreted initially your comments. But thankfully got the ache.